# I'm trying to find a specific sutta I think

Tags: the-buddha, pali-canon, sutras, texts

I remember there being a passage where a monk says to Buddha that he thinks the Sangha is at least 50 percent of the teaching and Buddha says something along the lines of 'it's all of it'. Can anyone help me find this or is my memory faulty and that's not what was actually said?

Answer (score 6):

[Upaddha Sutta: Half (of the Holy Life)](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn45/sn45.002.than.html)

> *Don't say that, Ananda. Don't say that. Admirable friendship, admirable companionship, admirable camaraderie is actually the whole
>   of the holy life. When a monk has admirable people as friends,
>   companions, & comrades, he can be expected to develop & pursue the
>   noble eightfold path.*